# How to compute the performance of a python program on different machines

Tags: python, performance, gpu, cpu, computation

I would like to know what are the different performance characteristics that can be used to find the performance of a python code on 2 different systems. Also is it possible to extend about its performance on a different machine? Is this kind of stuff possible?

Lets assume that one of the two systems is computation on GPU and other is on a CPU 
I want to extend the python code's performance on a CPU enabled different system.

Can this be also derived analytically?

Comment: Deleted last comments, now I read it differently. You want to plot python runtime against system characteristics to predict how fast code will run on different systems? A type of regression analysis?

Comment: Yes more or less, I want the same thing. As i said earlier, compare those performance characteristics and then for a new hardware, i want to analyze whether it would sustain or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences making assumptions based on hands on performance analysis has been sufficient for identifying initial instance sizes/requirements, and then using real time telemetry and instrumentation to closely monitor those solutions.

There are a couple ways, I've used, to commute performance (the terms are gibberish i've made up):

- **Informal Characterization of Bottlenecks**
  This has involved informally understanding where the bottlenecks of your application are likely to be, to give a very rough idea of capacity/machine requirements.  If you're performing CPU bound calculations with little to no network, then could bypassing starting with a network optimized instance.  Also if you're materializing processing to filesystem, and memory overhead is pretty small or bounded then you don't need a high memory instance.
- **External Performance Experiments**
  This involves creating performance test harnesses to establish base line experiments allowing you to change computer variables to determine what sort of effect they have on your program performance.  I like to setup queue based systems with throughput tests ie @10k requests / second what is the queue saturation, what is the service time.  It involves adding logging/telemetry to code to log those numbers.  Also setup a backlog to understand how fast a single instance can process a backlog.

For HTTP there are many tools to generate load.

Hopefully there is an automated tool to support your input format but if not you may have to write your own.

- **Performance Profiling**

I consider this using "low level" tools to scientifically (opposed to the informal analysis) determine where your code is spending its time.  Usually involves using [python profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to determine which routines you're spending time in, and then try to optimize them. http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html

For this step if the performance test harness has acceptable performance then this can be ignored :p

- **Real time telemetry**
  After acceptable performance and instance size has been determined, real time telemetry is critical to see how program is perform in real-time-ish to real life workloads.
  I've found Throughput, processing counts, errors, etc to all be critical to maintaining high performance systems:
  http://www.brendangregg.com/usemethod.html